# How to create a multimatch query with regex in java for elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, quarkus, resthighlevelclient

Im working with in Java, quarkus and elasticsearch, using quarkus-elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client and I have the following question for a search query:

It is possible to do a MultiMatchQuery with regEx? beacuse in my data I have two fields: "numberId1" and "numberId2", and in the search criteria I have a parameter that could match the last four digits of one of those fields, and I need to find a way to do that.

Example:
If my data is this:

```
[
{...,
numberId1: 45678,
numberId2:78523,
...,},
{...,
numberId1: 11111,
numberId2:105678,
...,},
{...,
numberId1: 22222,
numberId2:785823,
...,}
]
```

and if my shearch parameter is "5678" I have to return this ones:

```
[
{...,
numberId1: 45678,  (matches with numberId1)
numberId2:78523,
...,},
{...,
numberId1: 11111,
numberId2:105678,(matches with numberId12)
...,}
]
```

I was trying to do something like this to generate the search query but it doesnt work:

```
listRegEx.add(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("numberId1",".*"+searchParameter));  

                 listRegEx.add(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("numberId2",".*"+searchParameter));
    
for(RegexpQueryBuilder a:listRegEx){
      query.must(a);
}
```

I need something like multimatch with regex but I couldnt find out how to make it work

Something like this:

```
MultiMatchQueryBuilder mmqb=QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(".*"+searchParameter, 
                    "numberId1",
                    "numberId2");
            mmqb.type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.CROSS_FIELDS);
            mmqb.operator(Operator.AND);
            listMulti.add(mmqb);
```

Comment: What is the mapping of the numberX fields, because you cannot do this type of search if it's long, you need to have a text/wildcard type field

Comment: actually is just a string